# Jupiter notebook kernel dies when importing spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I am currently trying to import spaCy version 3.0.6 in a Jupiter notebook with the following code:

```
import spacy
```

But my kernel dies and I get the following message:

[image]

I tried updating conda and anaconda with `condo update conda` and `condo update anaconda`, but the issue persists. I also tried updating h5py and ipykernel. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling spacy. These were some solutions I found online but the problem persists. I am running this on a macOS with M1 chip. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same issue on spaCy Discussions https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7909

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before.
I tried to create a conda Env, install spacy packages there and add it to my jupyter notebook. Then run the jupyter notebook in that new conda Env then it works.